# I can't access to my sinatra webapp url using docker and passenger

Tags: ruby, docker, sinatra, passenger

I have to learn how to use docker, and how to dockerize a sinatra webapp.

I've followed this tutorial : http://coding.jandavid.de/2016/01/22/dockerizing-sinatra/

I'm now on the last section of this tutorial, that is to run my app with the url below: http://192.168.99.100:4567/ , but it's not working.

First of all, i've some questions about serveral parts of this tutorial.

1. In the `.conf` file, he's using the following line `passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby2.2;` and because i'm using Ruby 2.4.1 version, i've write this line of code `passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby2.4;`. That's right? What does mean this line?
2. In the Dockerfile, he's using the following line `FROM phusion/passenger-ruby22:0.9.18` where he write a specific version and i need to use this line below `FROM phusion/passenger-ruby24` because i'm using ruby 2.4.1, but i don't know if i need to specify a version.

When i'm building the image, all works perfectly, and when i'm starting my app with `docker run -p 4567:80 vcheloud/sinatra-example` all seems to works fine. But when i try to run http://192.168.99.100:4567/ it's not working.

Comment: Docker binds the port from inside the container to the host, so I don't see why in the tutorial it says you need to use this specific ip address. You could use `docker run -p 127.0.0.1:4567:80 vcheloud/sinatra-example` and in your localhost see the app running. However, I am interested to see what error you get anyway, in order to pinpoint your exact problem.

Comment: Thank you, it's works !
I did not have any errors before that works.

So i think that my `.conf`file and my Dockerfile are correct ?

Comment: the two points you mentioned don't seem to be problematic for your config files, and as long as you docker builds and nginx work fine then there shoudn't be a major issue with them related to what you described. If you face another issue, make sure next time post your configs to the question so people can track what's wrong and guide you.